# product displayed in one column only instead of 2 column on phone in magento 2.3

Tags: product, category-products, column, custom-column-grid

when you view a category on desktop shows 3 column but on mobile phone it shows product only **one column** instead of **two column** of the page.
whats wrong with magento 2.3.0

check the link on mobile device.
http://www.magshahindia.com/collections/yoga-new.html

Please advise, is it problem of magento 2.3.0 because in 2.2.7 there was no problem

Comment: I have edited my answer, please check

Answer (score 0):

In your custom CSS you have used **50% in width** reduce it to **49%** and that would be all.

find  **".products-grid .product-item"** in your stylesheet in media query

Comment: Asalamu alikum Shoaib Bhai.

Comment: Please advise which folder to go and which file to be edited ? Please advise are you from india?

Comment: You need to enable **Template Path Hint** for frontend, where you can find your file i.e, **list.phtml**. It would probably in vendor directory, you need to override it in you theme and add classes in **<li>** tag. I am from Pakistan :)

Comment: jazak allah brother can i add on instagram or whatsapp ?

Comment: Sorry brother, can't share in public. Did you find my answer useful?

Comment: @ShoaibMunir and just like that? M2.3.0 will work without bootstrap framework library on its own?

Comment: @crashtestxxx check the link that shezan shared, he already included bootstrap in his project, but he is not using it.

Comment: @ShoaibMunir Not sure where you see him including it, but it doesnt look like to me. On his page after you type `bootstrap` at the console, what do you see? I see it is not defined. Plus, I don't see a good reason, why @shezan would load another front-end library when Magento already comes with one.

Comment: @crashtestxxx I don't know why you are unable to see bootstrap in console. Please look at the screenshot https://www.screencast.com/t/2IeOu5fazcPr

Comment: @ShoaibMunir this is the Magento bootstrap, it is not same as open source Twitter library bootstrap you are talking about. It does not have same JavaScript components and styling classes.

Comment: Thanks @crashtestxxx for the information, i didn't know that magento has it own script with the name bootstrap.

Comment: @crashtestxxx I have edited my answer, based on the custom CSS that shezan used in his project. Thanks again for you input on it. I highly appreciate this

Comment: @ShoaibMunir absolutely, my pleasure. Btw, your new suggested answer will work as hackfix, but it is not an actual issue. If I'll get to it before anyone else will find a correct fix, I will post my answer.

Comment: guys thank you so much i am not a pro , i am normal mba student , dont know about magento and other stuffs , just learnt from youtube and magento posts , please advise how to have two column on mobile phone when website is viewed  ,please :)

Comment: @shezan check my answer, it will help you out. I have tried it in console, it was working fine